# Cannot create JsonNetResult to serialize json in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, json.net

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. In my project, I am returning json data to client. So I want to rename the properties of the json. So I tried to create JsonNetResult from this link https://yobriefca.se/blog/2010/11/20/better-json-serialisation-for-asp-dot-net-mvc/. But when I create that class, Visual Studio 2013 is giving me errors dealing with Newtonsoft.Json. Error seems to be a conflict.

See my screenshot:

[image]

[image]

I have never seen this error before. I also run update-package command recently. That errors show for only Newtonsoft.Json reference. How can I fix that error?

I am doing it to change json properties

```
public class Item{
   [JsonProperty("name")]
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("image_url")]
   public string ImageUrl{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you want to return your result in json ?

Comment: Yes. Changing property name using JsonProperty

Comment: if you want to convert your api response to json then use bellow code

Comment: Mine is not api. Just action of web controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //To produce JSON format
    var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(json);
```

Comment: add this code in WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Your one is for web api. Mine is not api. Just normal web controller action return type is JsonResult